# matplotlib vlines dynamic ymax parameter from seaborn distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting a `seaborn` `distplot` from pandas dataframe as my initial working matplotlib canvas. Then to add more info to the canvas I'm using `vlines` as vertical markers.
However I didn't find a trivial way to define dynamic `ymax` param for vlines, since it is distribution dependent.

```
sns.distplot(data.values) # distribution chart
plt.vlines(x=[1,2], ymin=0, ymax=?)
```

Is there a way to pass the `ymax` acccording to the highest value in the chart? (so the plot height and the vertical lines height will be aligned). I considered something like:

```
plt.vlines(x=[1,2], ymin=0, ymax=data.values.max())
```

However the maximal value of `data.values` is actually represented on the X axis.

Comment: are you looking for `ax.axvline(1)`  instead?

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - it partially solves the problem (I'm looking for vlines since in reality I want to plot multiple lines - edited the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to retrieve the coordinates of the canvas:

```
dist = sns.distplot(data.values)
ymin,ymax = dist.get_ylim()
```

Then it's quite straightforward:

```
plt.vlines(x=[1,2], ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may loop over the input points (useful if there aren't too many, say <=10)

```
for i in [1,2]:
    ax.axvline(i)
```

Or you can supply a blended transform for the `vlines`,

```
ax.vlines(x=[1,2], ymin=0, ymax=1, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
```